# react-testing-library test child component set data in parent component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to react-testing-library, in my project I have a parent-child component like this, where one of parent's states are set by passing a function as props to child component, and then called inside child component. I am just wondering if there is a way to mock that returned state from child component using react-testing-lib and jest? Thanks for all suggestions and ideas!

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(undefined);

    let getState= (state) => setState(state);

    return (
        // Something else...
        <Child getState={getState}/>
    )
}

const Child = ({getState}) => {
    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch(`someapi`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => 
                 // Do some other stuff
                 getState(data);
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    );

    return (
        //render something else
    )
}
```

Comment: `react-testing-library` generally encourages you to avoid mocking child components and instead interact with them directly. So if the child would react to a button press, then use a selector to get the button and click it. Your question is a little unclear to me in general, though because I don't understand the naming of `getState` (shouldn't that be `setState`?)

Answer (score -1):

useEffect snippet is not looking well. first of all you cant use fetchData because of this func. is private. you could use Child().

```
useEffect(() => {
    Child();
},[]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).